# How to customize Job ID of AWS Glue Jobs?

Tags: aws-glue

Is there any option to start job with a customize job id instead of some long string like "jr-.......". I would need to capture the job id but I want it to be a shorter one. Is it possible?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid, it is not possible